# How can compute instance has external ip and cloud nat both

Tags: google-compute-engine

compute instance default using cloud nat output to internet.

incoming using external ip to compute instance.

How can i do it??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use Cloud NAT for egress connections whenever VM instance has an external IP.

Please have a look at the documentation [Cloud NAT overview](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview) section [Specifications](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#specifications):

> Cloud NAT can be configured to provide NAT to the internet for packets
> sent from the following:
>
> - **The VM's network interface's primary internal IP address, provided that the network interface doesn't have an external IP address
>   assigned to it**. If the network interface has an external IP address
>   assigned to it, Google Cloud automatically performs one-to-one NAT for
>   packets whose sources match the interface's primary internal IP
>   address because the network interface meets the Google Cloud internet
>   access requirements. **The existence of an external IP address on an
>   interface always takes precedence and always performs one-to-one NAT,
>   without using Cloud NAT**.

Comment: Please upvote/accept my answer if it was useful.